# NSUnknownKeyException setValue:forUndefinedKey

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using Core Data.

I have this in my View Controller:

```
        double bearingSave = course;
        double widthSave = inFeet;
        NSString *fieldName = @"BLAHBLAHBLAH";
        double acres = 5;

        AppDelegate *appDelegate =
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context =
        [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *newContact;
        newContact = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newContact setValue: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:bearingSave] forKey:@"bearing"];
        [newContact setValue: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:widthSave] forKey:@"width"];

//THIS ONE IS CAUSING ERROR
        [newContact setValue: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acres] forKey:@"acres"];
```

I keep getting this message:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObject 0x6080000b3b60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Contacts is not key value coding-compliant for the key "acres".
```

I have "acres" as an attribute in my Contacts entity as shown:

[image: XCDATAMODEL]

I've tried multiple simulators and even deleted the simulators and tried again and still continue to get the error.

Comment: Could there be a typo in your MOM? Maybe there's an invisible space after "acres" or something. You can examine the model file directly; it's just an XML file wrapped up in a package, so you can read it with any text editor.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I opened the model with a separate editor and noticed that the XML sheet wasn't generating all the attributes. I wonder why they would show up in XCode, but not really be there.

Comment: I've no idea. The idea that the GUI display in Xcode could somehow not match the underlying XML reality is sort of stunning. Maybe it would have helped to empty the DerivedData caches. Anyway, I'm glad I thought of suggesting you look under the hood!

Answer (score 0):

Things are not as they appear.

I opened the data model file in the XCode project directory with another text editor other than XCode. It became clear that the XCode generated data model file was missing attributes that were being shown in the XCode GUI Entity editor.

Not sure why it was different. I added the attributes to the data model with the other text editor and it worked fine.